# How to caluculate Sum In ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please help me. How can I calculate ROW_NUMBER total Records
I have a table, CustTable:

```
ID   Name 
1    John
2    Mick
3    MD
4    Smith
```

Here i want to do pagination if a user enters more than the total rows then its its through an alert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CustPaginantion (@PageNum int,@TotalPages int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustId) AS UNIQID,
           COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY CustId) AS cnt,
           CustId,
           CustName,
           CustAddress
    FROM Customer
    ORDER BY UNIQID
    OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@TotalPages ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @TotalPages ROWS ONLY
END
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? It can't be both.

Comment: its sql Server 2012

Comment: Then don't tag MySQL (I've updated your post). I'm not really sure what you're asking though. Are you wanting to generate an error if the SP won't return a result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustId) AS UNIQID,
       COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY CustId) AS cnt,
       CustId,
       CustName,
       CustAddress
FROM Customer
ORDER BY UNIQID
OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@TotalPages ROWS
FETCH NEXT @TotalPages ROWS ONLY

IF @@ROWCOUNT > @TotalPages
    RAISERROR(' user enters more than the total rows',1,1)
```